# Pass empty argument in java (to be parsed as not getting any agrument al all)

Tags: java, arguments, argument-passing

I was wondering if there is any way in java to pass an argument to a method which is actually read by java as not getting any argument at all. More concrete: 
I have got two versions of a method, one requiring one argument and the other none at all. So when the method is called without an argument the second version is executed. Is there a way to actually pass an empty argument which java reads as not being provided with an argument at all?

```
void exampleMethod(){
    // do stuff
}

void exampleMethod(arg){
    // do other stuff
}
```

I would like to be able to call

```
exampleMethod(?);
```

So that the first version of the method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way is to override the method:

```
void method(Object arg) {
    if(org  == null) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}

void method() {
    methode(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I considered using the if-statement but was hoping to find a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Another way is using variable arguments. But in both cases you have to check the null case.

Comment: Okay I'll go with an ternary operator then!